# Reference to xml_****_**** is ambiguous

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, xcode8, xmppframework

I have updated my Xcode to the latest version of 8.0
After the update, I am facing a new build error preventing me to run the project on the simulator.

The error is the below in DDXMLNode.m:

```
reference to 'XML_DOCUMENT_NODE' is ambiguous
```

I am using the XMPP framework as pods (pod 'XMPPFramework') so I still can't figure out a way to solve this. 
Note that the project is working normally on the device and was working on both Device and Simulator with the previous Xcode Version.

I have tried to search the internet but I still didn't find any solution for this.
I tried to clean the project and delete everything in the DerivedData folder as well, but it didn't solve the issue.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I am posting this answer in case it may help someone in the future.

After searching a lot without finding any answer, I discovered the following:
There is a file called module.modulemap that contains 2 methods.

```
module libxml [system] {
    header "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/tree.h"
    export *
}

module libxmlSimu [system] {
    header "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/tree.h"
    export *
}
```

The first one is used for real devices, the other one for the simulator.
However, when building the app on the simulator, and for a reason that I didnt figure it out, tree.h is being duplicated and causing all these issue.

So what I made to be able to run the project on the simulator was to comment the first method so the app can build successfully.

**NB:** Don't forget to uncomment the method once you want to run the project again on the real device.

Hope this will help anyone who will face the same issue.

Answer (score -1):

i have tried some way.
I search the word `XML_DOCUMENT_NODE` with a result here:

[image]

then replace every error with the left symbol. It turns out to be OK for me now.

Comment: check my answer, it may help you in case you were facing the same issue.